# does CCTableView only work for iOS devices?

Tags: cross-platform, cocos2d-x

I am making my first cross platform app with cocos2d-x and was wondering if the extensions work on android apps also.

I do not have a test environment setup for android to test it out yet, but was just wondering if my code would work cross platform or i would have to come up with another method.

Comment: Whatever You work on cocos2d-x will definitely work on Android devices . . . . What You have to do is just build for android ... check it out this :                           http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CCTableView in your cocos2d-x & that will also work for Android Devices along with Ios Devices ..

For Environment Setup you can follow this link :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started